# Can someone explain the ending of Sahib Biwi Aur Ghulam?

Tags: plot-explanation, sahib-biwi-aur-ghulam

Is Choti Bahu killed by Majle Babu's henchmen in 1962's movie Sahib Biwi Aur Ghulam? If yes, then why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in the movie, Choti Bahu was killed by the henchman. The reason behind it is unknown. It's like the movie ended on a note where it's left to the audience to think and interpret the story.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Choti Bahu was killed by the henchmen of Majhle Babu because he suspected that Choti Bahu was having affair with Bhootnath (though really it was not). There are some scenes in the movie where Chote Babu sees Bhoothnath coming to the 'haveli' and talking to Choti Bahu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Sapru's henchmen kills her. Sapru watches her mount the buggy and asks about who went in it . Then we are shown that relics of a woman are found when Gurudutt is demolishing the haveli. So it is anybody's guess.

Comment: How is your answer different from other already present answer ?